# idiom or a smooth way to say that the game is the right level/scope for a person?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for a way to say that a certain game is challenging enough (but not too much) and of the right scope. So far I came up with 'This game is in my league' but that doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: What is wrong with 'at my level', which is totally idiomatic?

Comment: You could say it was in the "Goldilocks zone" (not too hard, not too easy).

Answer (score 1):

"just right"

"The difficulty of this game is just right for me"

Answer (score 0):

"In my wheelhouse" could work, but often refers to skill sets more so than interests.

"Up my alley" could also work for you.

You might even just say "age-appropriate" if you're talking about the right challenge rating for younger folks.